# How to find .asc files 5 folders deep?

Tags: python, os.walk

I have several .asc files hidden 5 folders deep.  For example:

```
main > Folder1a > Folder2a > Folder3a > Folder4a > myfile1.asc 
main > Folder1b > Folder2b > Folder3b > Folder4b > myfile2.asc 
main > Folder1c > Folder2c > Folder3c > Folder4c > myfile3.asc
```

What method can I use to get a list of `myfile.asc` files contained within the `main` folder?

Answer (score 2):

```
f_walker = os.walk("/path/to/main")
f_generator = (os.path.join(cur,file) for cur,f,d in f_walker for file in f)
all_files = [file for file in f_generator if file.endswith(".asc")]
```

I think ... but it might go slow if you know they will only ever be 5 levels deep (never 4 and never 6... then you can optimize this some)

for example something like this might be much faster

```
import os
import glob

def go_deep(base_path,pattern,depth):
    if depth > 0:
        for fname in os.listdir(base_path):
            full_path = os.path.join(base_path,fname)
            if os.path.isdir(full_path):
                for fpath in go_deep(full_path,pattern,depth-1):
                    yield fpath
    else:
        for fname in glob.glob(pattern):
            yield os.path.join(base_path,fname)

print list(go_deep(".",pattern="*.asc",depth=5))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Give the extension with the dot.   Directory does not need quotes.  Basically same as Joran's answer with input from user.  Did this for another project...

```
import os

extension = input("enter extension:")
directory = input("enter directory to start in:")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for fname in files:
        if fname.endswith(extension):
            full_fname = os.path.join(root, fname)
            print(full_fname)
```